# I need to place Linear Layout over v4.view.ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

[image: This is the layout when I use Linear Layout, if I use Relative layout, everything disappears]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/view_pager"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/image_count"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#00000000">
  </LinearLayout>

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It creates ViewPager Fragment and a space for Linear Layout (This linear layout shows the current page selected with use of dots) and a map fragment.  What I want is to place the linear layout currently in the middle of the XML layout to be on the ViewPager and NOT BELOW IT. How can I do it.  I've tried my hands on FrameLayout but it messes up everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` to set view on top of another

Comment: On using RelativeLayout everything disappears.  I've attached a screenshot for LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

With LinearLayout, elements will be ordered in row or columns. Use Relative Layout instead.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/view_pager"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dip"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/image_count"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#00000000">
  </LinearLayout>

   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: on using relative layout all elements disappear on the layout.